# Android - Accessing a variable in Activity (Using synchronization)

Tags: java, android

I have a question in synchronization between threads in Android.

What I have is:

2 thread spawned from an activity, and each of this thread is accessing a field in the activity simultaneously.

What I am thinking of is to use synchronize, such as

```
synchronize private void functionA()
```

or

```
synchronize(mContext){  
....  
}
```

(where mContext is context of activity)

But I am not sure if it will really work.

Or does anyone has any better ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a pretty good example - you make the variable private and then create synchronized getter and setter functions:

```
class Account {
    private double balance;             // make variable private

    // write synchronized accessor methods
    public synchronized void setBalance(double b) {
        balance = b;
    }

    public synchronized double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    // modify update method to use accessor methods
    synchronized void updateBalance(double amount) {
    //    double b = getBalance();
        setBalance( getBalance() + amount);
    }
}
```

source: http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/threads/synchronized.html

and here's another example, this time using ArrayList:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#concurrencyjava_synchronized

Answer (score 0):

The synchronize can do this and make the thread synchronously.